# Can I manually make tcp zero window and drop?

Tags: c, tcp, network-programming, tcpclient, sliding-window

I have to request specific directory repeatedly. ex) https://example.org/home/dir/aaa/11
There is case if http response status code is 200 or else. If 200? read data from raw socket&and if there is 404, drop remainder packets.  ex

```
    int bytes_received = SSL_read(ssl, response, 1370);
    printf("%s\nreceive : %d", response, bytes_received);
    if(strstr(response, "HTTP1.1 200 OK") goto(specific behavior);
else{drop; goto(ssl_write)}; // goto first send point, I want to drop remainder packets in kernel buffer from this point.  
    puts("");
```

Is this possible by manually modifying Kernel, or tcp structure or size of sliding window? Or else? If can't, then why? Thx.

Comment: Please don't use `goto` and labels. They tend to make spaghetti of the code, making it hard to follow and understand and maintain.

Comment: And be careful to print strings you receive, unless you definitely and 100% know they will contain no arbitrary binary data, and will always be properly null-terminated.

Comment: Furthermore, assuming TCP it's a streaming protocol where the connection is just a stream of bytes. There's no "messages" or other boundaries. As such there's no guarantee that a single receive call will return the number of bytes requests You always have to check what's actually returned, not only for size but also for errors and a closed connection.

Comment: You seem to be using SSL, so you're not interacting directly with the TCP stream. You need to interact through the SSL layer, not directly with the socket.

Comment: thx above all..I'll take care all of above. Can I request server to not send remainder packets without breaking session?